# Getting total number of checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a form with checkboxes with the input being stored in an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="lineup[]" value="1">Tom</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="lineup[]" value="2">David</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="lineup[]" value="3">Sarah</input>
```

Using jQuery I want to find how many checkboxes are ticked/checked:

```
var total=$(this).find('input[name=lineup]').serialize();

alert(total.length);
```

However the total is always output a 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the docs http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and use google.

Comment: You know that `.serialize();` returns a string? What is `this` in your code? Also, `input[name=lineup]` won't match any of your elements, since their name is `lineup[]` not `lineup`.

Comment: two minutes, actually seconds, on google or stackoverflow would have answered this question. down vote

Comment: I used '$(this)' since I have two forms with identical structure, I thought by using $(this) I can ensure that the required form input is used? I had also tried using the square brackets because of couse the form input is passed in an array, but when I did this the jquery had an error although I guess the error was else where. I did google  this and did find some answers elsewhere on the site but again when I tried these I couldn't get things working hence my question. I did try!

Comment: @AlanA: Using `$(this)` is fine, but without your explanation, we couldn't know which element `this` refers to. For example, if it referred to one of the input elements, then it would obviously not work. That's why I asked. Without knowing which element `this` refers to, it is actually impossible to truly answer your question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `:checked` in the selector, and don't serialize it, just get the length.

```
var total=$(this).find('input[name="lineup[]"]:checked').length;
```

Also use `[]` in the selector, because your checkboxes use `[]` in the name. As [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) points out, it is part of the name and so you have to explicitly specify the `[]`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2qrtq/)

Comment: +1 For being the only one so far getting the selector right. Though *"your checkboxes are an input array"* is not a good explanation IMO. The `[]` in the name have no significance in JS, HTML or HTTP. Only PHP treats them differently and creates an array. But in this context, the `[]` are just part of the name, that's it.

Comment: @FelixKling agree with that :), updated thanks. Other server side languages will parse it as an array such as ASP.NET but you are correct that as far as Javascript and the browser is concerned, it is just a name.

Comment: I didn't know about ASP.NET, good to know! The other languages I know (e.g. Python) will treat all values with the same name as array. You don't need the `[]` to indicate this. So for Python (for example), simply using `name="lineup"` would work as well. That's why I'm emphasizing that it actually doesn't mean anything by itself. Happy coding! :)

Comment: I didn't know that Python would do it without `[]` so I guess you learn something new everyday, cheers :)

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
 alert($('input[name=lineup]:checked').length);
```

your way

```
$(this).find('input[name=lineup]:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
var checkedBoxes = $('input[name=lineup]:checked').length;
alert(checkedBoxes);
```

Comment: isn't it `alert(checkedBoxes)`, because you already got length in that varibale??